# Queue closes after difficult job

Tags: laravel, queue

**After processing the excel file, for about 60 seconds, the queue drops.**
***And it may not end.***
[image]

**Why is the queue falling?**

Comment: You should probably check your PHP logs and see if that has any more information. I would imagine it is reaching its max execution time limit and so the process is being killed.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did not find anything in the logs. It seems to me that the queue simply drops due to the difficult process. But I don’t know how to fix it.

Comment: And I changed the default settings in the method. set_time_limit(0); ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

Answer (score 0):

> Decided by adding **--memory=2048**

*php artisan queue:work redis --queue=process --tries=0 --delay=0 --timeout=120 --sleep=5* **--memory=2048**